# Problems with simple_form: has_many and belongs_to not creating ID column?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have three models, `Neo`, `User`(autogenerated by Devise) and `Observation`.

Every `User` `has_many` `Neo`s and `Observation`s.
Every `Neo` `has_many` Observations and `belongs_to` an `User`.
Every `Observation` `belongs_to` one `Neo` and to one `User`.

I need to create a simple_form for a Neo, which should allow me to add Observations dynamically (a la Polldaddy poll options). This is my form code:

```
- title "Add a NEO"

= simple_form_for @neo do |nf|
    = nf.input :name
        = nf.simple_fields_for :observations do |of|
            = of.input :ra
            = of.input :dec

    = nf.button :wrapped
```

This returns an `ActiveRecord::UnkownAttributeError` saying "unknown attribute `neo_id`".

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My indentation was wrong:

```
- title "Add a NEO"

= simple_form_for @neo do |nf|
    = nf.input :name
        = nf.simple_fields_for :observations do |of|
            = of.input :ra
            = of.input :dec

    = nf.button :wrapped
```

should have been:

```
- title "Add a NEO"

= simple_form_for @neo do |nf|
    = nf.input :name
    = nf.simple_fields_for :observations do |of|
        = of.input :ra
        = of.input :dec

    = nf.button :wrapped
```